# How to play a Youtube video in python

Tags: python, api, youtube

What modules should I use to make a Python script where Python gets the name of a video, opens up a Chrome window, opens Youtube and plays the first result. I've tried Youtube Data API but it's not for that kind of things.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not for that kind of things?"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the subprocess to call a browser and run the url you request. With this minimal code you can ask for a website to go, and open in firefox. But you can use it as a bootstrap code for your application using `chrome`.

```
import subprocess
url = input('What site you would to go: ')
subprocess.Popen(['firefox',url])
```

Using this template, you can just change the code to ask for a youtube link. If you have firefox installed you can just run it.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver

# You could also use Chrome, I just default to Firefox
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('URL within some quotes')

# And if you want full-screen, finish it off with
driver.maximize_window()
```

And boom, that's a really quick way to open a site. You need to pip install selenium, of course, but this is my preferred way. Just wanted to offer an additional option.